# how can we have or condition in rendered attribute

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I have rendered condition like below mentioned.
    ui:fragment rendered="#{ navigationBean.currentUri == '/login/selectEnv.jsf' ||   navigationBean.currentUri == '/home/home.jsf'}"

but the || condition is not working.Is it possible to check two conditions in rendered attribute.Is there any aleternative to this?

Comment: It should just work. Please describe the symptoms in more detail. You can always try the keyword `or` instead of `||` but that shouldn't make any difference as `||` should just work. Apparently the `currentUri` doesn't return the value you expected to return. Just debug it.

Comment: if I use single condition it is working fine but if I keep two conditions using || operator it is not working.Also I have tried both the condition individually they are working fine.Can we use || operator in rendered attribute.The same || operator I have used for disabled attribute it is working for that attribute.

Comment: Well, the problem is not visible in the code posted so far. A real SSCCE would be more helpful, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use or operation by using 'or' keyword.

```
 ui:fragment rendered="#{ navigationBean.currentUri == '/login/selectEnv.jsf' or  
     navigationBean.currentUri == '/home/home.jsf'}"
```